# openSSL 3.0 deprecation errors when compiling wpa_supplicant-2.10

Tags: 22.04, compiling, openssl, radius

On Ubuntu 22.04 server

I am trying to compile eapol_test from wpa_supplicant-2.10 as found on

https://w1.fi/wpa_supplicant/

`make eapol_test`

(Following "THE FREERADIUS IMPLEMENTATION GUIDE" (2014 network radius sarl) chapter 6 -EAP authentication, Pg 46,47)
https://networkradius.com/doc/FreeRADIUS-Implementation-Ch6.pdf

I've set

`CONFIG_EAPOL_TEST=y`

in the .config

I get plenty of "deprecated: Since OpenSSL 3.0" errors. (on Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS)
The full output is below.

Thanks in advance for your advice,

```
  CC  config.c
  CC  notify.c
  CC  bss.c
  CC  eap_register.c
  CC  ../src/utils/common.c
  CC  ../src/utils/config.c
  CC  ../src/utils/wpa_debug.c
  CC  ../src/utils/wpabuf.c
  CC  ../src/utils/bitfield.c
  CC  ../src/utils/ip_addr.c
  CC  ../src/utils/crc32.c
  CC  op_classes.c
  CC  rrm.c
  CC  twt.c
  CC  robust_av.c
  CC  wmm_ac.c
  CC  ../src/utils/os_unix.c
  CC  ../src/utils/eloop.c
  CC  config_file.c
  CC  ../src/rsn_supp/wpa_ft.c
  CC  ../src/common/sae.c
  CC  ../src/common/dpp.c
  CC  ../src/common/dpp_auth.c
  CC  ../src/common/dpp_backup.c
  CC  ../src/common/dpp_crypto.c
  CC  ../src/common/dpp_pkex.c
  CC  ../src/common/dpp_reconfig.c
  CC  ../src/common/dpp_tcp.c
  CC  dpp_supplicant.c
  CC  ../src/rsn_supp/tdls.c
  CC  ../src/rsn_supp/wpa.c
  CC  ../src/rsn_supp/preauth.c
  CC  ../src/rsn_supp/pmksa_cache.c
  CC  ../src/rsn_supp/wpa_ie.c
  CC  ../src/common/wpa_common.c
  CC  ibss_rsn.c
  CC  p2p_supplicant.c
  CC  p2p_supplicant_sd.c
  CC  ../src/p2p/p2p.c
  CC  ../src/p2p/p2p_utils.c
  CC  ../src/p2p/p2p_parse.c
  CC  ../src/p2p/p2p_build.c
  CC  ../src/p2p/p2p_go_neg.c
  CC  ../src/p2p/p2p_sd.c
  CC  ../src/p2p/p2p_pd.c
  CC  ../src/p2p/p2p_invitation.c
  CC  ../src/p2p/p2p_dev_disc.c
  CC  ../src/p2p/p2p_group.c
  CC  ../src/ap/p2p_hostapd.c
  CC  wifi_display.c
  CC  hs20_supplicant.c
  CC  interworking.c
  CC  ../src/eap_peer/eap_tls.c
  CC  ../src/eap_peer/eap_peap.c
  CC  ../src/eap_common/eap_peap_common.c
  CC  ../src/eap_peer/eap_ttls.c
  CC  ../src/eap_peer/eap_md5.c
  CC  ../src/eap_peer/eap_mschapv2.c
  CC  ../src/eap_peer/mschapv2.c
  CC  ../src/eap_peer/eap_gtc.c
  CC  ../src/eap_peer/eap_otp.c
  CC  ../src/eap_peer/eap_leap.c
  CC  ../src/eap_peer/eap_fast.c
  CC  ../src/eap_peer/eap_fast_pac.c
  CC  ../src/eap_common/eap_fast_common.c
  CC  ../src/eap_peer/eap_pax.c
  CC  ../src/eap_common/eap_pax_common.c
  CC  ../src/eap_peer/eap_sake.c
  CC  ../src/eap_common/eap_sake_common.c
  CC  ../src/eap_peer/eap_gpsk.c
  CC  ../src/eap_common/eap_gpsk_common.c
  CC  ../src/eap_peer/eap_pwd.c
  CC  ../src/eap_common/eap_pwd_common.c
  CC  wps_supplicant.c
  CC  ../src/utils/uuid.c
  CC  ../src/eap_peer/eap_wsc.c
  CC  ../src/eap_common/eap_wsc_common.c
  CC  ../src/wps/wps.c
  CC  ../src/wps/wps_common.c
  CC  ../src/wps/wps_attr_parse.c
  CC  ../src/wps/wps_attr_build.c
  CC  ../src/wps/wps_attr_process.c
  CC  ../src/wps/wps_dev_attr.c
  CC  ../src/wps/wps_enrollee.c
  CC  ../src/wps/wps_registrar.c
  CC  ../src/eap_peer/eap_ikev2.c
  CC  ../src/eap_peer/ikev2.c
  CC  ../src/eap_common/eap_ikev2_common.c
  CC  ../src/eap_common/ikev2_common.c
  CC  ../src/eap_peer/eap_tnc.c
  CC  ../src/eap_peer/tncc.c
  CC  wpas_kay.c
  CC  ../src/pae/ieee802_1x_cp.c
  CC  ../src/pae/ieee802_1x_kay.c
  CC  ../src/pae/ieee802_1x_key.c
  CC  ../src/pae/ieee802_1x_secy_ops.c
  CC  ../src/ap/wpa_auth_kay.c
  CC  ../src/eapol_supp/eapol_supp_sm.c
  CC  ../src/eap_peer/eap.c
  CC  ../src/eap_peer/eap_methods.c
  CC  ap.c
  CC  ../src/ap/hostapd.c
  CC  ../src/ap/wpa_auth_glue.c
  CC  ../src/ap/utils.c
  CC  ../src/ap/authsrv.c
  CC  ../src/ap/ap_config.c
  CC  ../src/ap/sta_info.c
  CC  ../src/ap/tkip_countermeasures.c
  CC  ../src/ap/ap_mlme.c
  CC  ../src/ap/ieee802_1x.c
  CC  ../src/eapol_auth/eapol_auth_sm.c
  CC  ../src/ap/ieee802_11_auth.c
  CC  ../src/ap/ieee802_11_shared.c
  CC  ../src/ap/drv_callbacks.c
  CC  ../src/ap/ap_drv_ops.c
  CC  ../src/ap/beacon.c
  CC  ../src/ap/bss_load.c
  CC  ../src/ap/eap_user_db.c
  CC  ../src/ap/neighbor_db.c
  CC  ../src/ap/rrm.c
  CC  ../src/ap/ieee802_11_ht.c
  CC  ../src/ap/ieee802_11_vht.c
  CC  ../src/ap/ctrl_iface_ap.c
  CC  ../src/eap_server/eap_server.c
  CC  ../src/eap_server/eap_server_identity.c
  CC  ../src/eap_server/eap_server_methods.c
  CC  ../src/ap/wmm.c
  CC  ../src/ap/ap_list.c
  CC  ../src/ap/ieee802_11.c
  CC  ../src/ap/hw_features.c
  CC  ../src/ap/dfs.c
  CC  ../src/ap/wps_hostapd.c
  CC  ../src/eap_server/eap_server_wsc.c
  CC  ../src/ap/dpp_hostapd.c
  CC  ../src/ap/gas_query_ap.c
  CC  ../src/ap/gas_serv.c
  CC  ../src/ap/hs20.c
  CC  ../src/ap/wpa_auth.c
  CC  ../src/ap/wpa_auth_ie.c
  CC  ../src/ap/pmksa_cache_auth.c
  CC  ../src/common/dragonfly.c
  CC  ../src/crypto/ms_funcs.c
  CC  ../src/eap_common/chap.c
  CC  ../src/eap_peer/eap_tls_common.c
../src/crypto/tls_openssl.c: In function ‘tls_engine_load_dynamic_generic’:
../src/crypto/tls_openssl.c:799:9: error: ‘ENGINE_by_id’ is deprecated: Since OpenSSL 3.0 [-Werror=deprecated-declarations]
  799 |         engine = ENGINE_by_id(id);
      |         ^~~~~~
In file included from ../src/crypto/tls_openssl.c:25:
/usr/include/openssl/engine.h:336:31: note: declared here
  336 | OSSL_DEPRECATEDIN_3_0 ENGINE *ENGINE_by_id(const char *id);
      |                               ^~~~~~~~~~~~
../src/crypto/tls_openssl.c:814:9: error: ‘ENGINE_by_id’ is deprecated: Since OpenSSL 3.0 [-Werror=deprecated-declarations]
  814 |         engine = ENGINE_by_id(dynamic_id);
      |         ^~~~~~
In file included from ../src/crypto/tls_openssl.c:25:
/usr/include/openssl/engine.h:336:31: note: declared here
  336 | OSSL_DEPRECATEDIN_3_0 ENGINE *ENGINE_by_id(const char *id);
      |                               ^~~~~~~~~~~~
../src/crypto/tls_openssl.c:825:17: error: ‘ENGINE_ctrl_cmd_string’ is deprecated: Since OpenSSL 3.0 [-Werror=deprecated-declarations]
  825 |                 if (ENGINE_ctrl_cmd_string(engine, pre[0], pre[1], 0) == 0) {
      |                 ^~
In file included from ../src/crypto/tls_openssl.c:25:
/usr/include/openssl/engine.h:479:5: note: declared here
  479 | int ENGINE_ctrl_cmd_string(ENGINE *e, const char *cmd_name, const char *arg,
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../src/crypto/tls_openssl.c:829:25: error: ‘ENGINE_free’ is deprecated: Since OpenSSL 3.0 [-Werror=deprecated-declarations]
  829 |                         ENGINE_free(engine);
      |                         ^~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from ../src/crypto/tls_openssl.c:25:
/usr/include/openssl/engine.h:493:27: note: declared here
  493 | OSSL_DEPRECATEDIN_3_0 int ENGINE_free(ENGINE *e);
      |                           ^~~~~~~~~~~
../src/crypto/tls_openssl.c:839:9: error: ‘ENGINE_free’ is deprecated: Since OpenSSL 3.0 [-Werror=deprecated-declarations]
  839 |         ENGINE_free(engine);
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from ../src/crypto/tls_openssl.c:25:
/usr/include/openssl/engine.h:493:27: note: declared here
  493 | OSSL_DEPRECATEDIN_3_0 int ENGINE_free(ENGINE *e);
      |                           ^~~~~~~~~~~
../src/crypto/tls_openssl.c:841:9: error: ‘ENGINE_by_id’ is deprecated: Since OpenSSL 3.0 [-Werror=deprecated-declarations]
  841 |         engine = ENGINE_by_id(id);
      |         ^~~~~~
In file included from ../src/crypto/tls_openssl.c:25:
/usr/include/openssl/engine.h:336:31: note: declared here
  336 | OSSL_DEPRECATEDIN_3_0 ENGINE *ENGINE_by_id(const char *id);
      |                               ^~~~~~~~~~~~
../src/crypto/tls_openssl.c:850:17: error: ‘ENGINE_ctrl_cmd_string’ is deprecated: Since OpenSSL 3.0 [-Werror=deprecated-declarations]
  850 |                 if (ENGINE_ctrl_cmd_string(engine, post[0], post[1], 0) == 0) {
      |                 ^~
In file included from ../src/crypto/tls_openssl.c:25:
/usr/include/openssl/engine.h:479:5: note: declared here
  479 | int ENGINE_ctrl_cmd_string(ENGINE *e, const char *cmd_name, const char *arg,
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../src/crypto/tls_openssl.c:854:25: error: ‘ENGINE_remove’ is deprecated: Since OpenSSL 3.0 [-Werror=deprecated-declarations]
  854 |                         ENGINE_remove(engine);
      |                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from ../src/crypto/tls_openssl.c:25:
/usr/include/openssl/engine.h:332:27: note: declared here
  332 | OSSL_DEPRECATEDIN_3_0 int ENGINE_remove(ENGINE *e);
      |                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
../src/crypto/tls_openssl.c:855:25: error: ‘ENGINE_free’ is deprecated: Since OpenSSL 3.0 [-Werror=deprecated-declarations]
  855 |                         ENGINE_free(engine);
      |                         ^~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from ../src/crypto/tls_openssl.c:25:
/usr/include/openssl/engine.h:493:27: note: declared here
  493 | OSSL_DEPRECATEDIN_3_0 int ENGINE_free(ENGINE *e);
      |                           ^~~~~~~~~~~
../src/crypto/tls_openssl.c:860:9: error: ‘ENGINE_free’ is deprecated: Since OpenSSL 3.0 [-Werror=deprecated-declarations]
  860 |         ENGINE_free(engine);
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from ../src/crypto/tls_openssl.c:25:
/usr/include/openssl/engine.h:493:27: note: declared here
  493 | OSSL_DEPRECATEDIN_3_0 int ENGINE_free(ENGINE *e);
      |                           ^~~~~~~~~~~
../src/crypto/tls_openssl.c: In function ‘tls_init’:
../src/crypto/tls_openssl.c:1089:9: error: ‘ENGINE_load_builtin_engines’ is deprecated: Since OpenSSL 3.0 [-Werror=deprecated-declarations]
 1089 |         ENGINE_load_builtin_engines();
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from ../src/crypto/tls_openssl.c:25:
/usr/include/openssl/engine.h:358:28: note: declared here
  358 | OSSL_DEPRECATEDIN_3_0 void ENGINE_load_builtin_engines(void);
      |                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../src/crypto/tls_openssl.c: In function ‘tls_engine_init’:
../src/crypto/tls_openssl.c:1213:9: error: ‘ENGINE_by_id’ is deprecated: Since OpenSSL 3.0 [-Werror=deprecated-declarations]
 1213 |         conn->engine = ENGINE_by_id(engine_id);
      |         ^~~~
In file included from ../src/crypto/tls_openssl.c:25:
/usr/include/openssl/engine.h:336:31: note: declared here
  336 | OSSL_DEPRECATEDIN_3_0 ENGINE *ENGINE_by_id(const char *id);
      |                               ^~~~~~~~~~~~
../src/crypto/tls_openssl.c:1219:9: error: ‘ENGINE_init’ is deprecated: Since OpenSSL 3.0 [-Werror=deprecated-declarations]
 1219 |         if (ENGINE_init(conn->engine) != 1) {
      |         ^~
In file included from ../src/crypto/tls_openssl.c:25:
/usr/include/openssl/engine.h:620:27: note: declared here
  620 | OSSL_DEPRECATEDIN_3_0 int ENGINE_init(ENGINE *e);
      |                           ^~~~~~~~~~~
../src/crypto/tls_openssl.c:1228:9: error: ‘ENGINE_ctrl_cmd_string’ is deprecated: Since OpenSSL 3.0 [-Werror=deprecated-declarations]
 1228 |         if (pin && ENGINE_ctrl_cmd_string(conn->engine, "PIN", pin, 0) == 0) {
      |         ^~
In file included from ../src/crypto/tls_openssl.c:25:
/usr/include/openssl/engine.h:479:5: note: declared here
  479 | int ENGINE_ctrl_cmd_string(ENGINE *e, const char *cmd_name, const char *arg,
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../src/crypto/tls_openssl.c:1245:17: error: ‘ENGINE_load_private_key’ is deprecated: Since OpenSSL 3.0 [-Werror=deprecated-declarations]
 1245 |                 conn->private_key = ENGINE_load_private_key(conn->engine,
      |                 ^~~~
In file included from ../src/crypto/tls_openssl.c:25:
/usr/include/openssl/engine.h:638:11: note: declared here
  638 | EVP_PKEY *ENGINE_load_private_key(ENGINE *e, const char *key_id,
      |           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../src/crypto/tls_openssl.c:1268:17: error: ‘ENGINE_ctrl’ is deprecated: Since OpenSSL 3.0 [-Werror=deprecated-declarations]
 1268 |                 if (!ENGINE_ctrl(conn->engine, ENGINE_CTRL_GET_CMD_FROM_NAME,
      |                 ^~
In file included from ../src/crypto/tls_openssl.c:25:
/usr/include/openssl/engine.h:429:27: note: declared here
  429 | OSSL_DEPRECATEDIN_3_0 int ENGINE_ctrl(ENGINE *e, int cmd, long i, void *p,
      |                           ^~~~~~~~~~~
../src/crypto/tls_openssl.c:1281:17: error: ‘ENGINE_free’ is deprecated: Since OpenSSL 3.0 [-Werror=deprecated-declarations]
 1281 |                 ENGINE_free(conn->engine);
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from ../src/crypto/tls_openssl.c:25:
/usr/include/openssl/engine.h:493:27: note: declared here
  493 | OSSL_DEPRECATEDIN_3_0 int ENGINE_free(ENGINE *e);
      |                           ^~~~~~~~~~~
../src/crypto/tls_openssl.c: In function ‘tls_engine_deinit’:
../src/crypto/tls_openssl.c:1307:17: error: ‘ENGINE_finish’ is deprecated: Since OpenSSL 3.0 [-Werror=deprecated-declarations]
 1307 |                 ENGINE_finish(conn->engine);
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from ../src/crypto/tls_openssl.c:25:
/usr/include/openssl/engine.h:628:27: note: declared here
  628 | OSSL_DEPRECATEDIN_3_0 int ENGINE_finish(ENGINE *e);
      |                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
../src/crypto/tls_openssl.c: In function ‘tls_engine_get_cert’:
../src/crypto/tls_openssl.c:3605:9: error: ‘ENGINE_ctrl_cmd’ is deprecated: Since OpenSSL 3.0 [-Werror=deprecated-declarations]
 3605 |         if (!ENGINE_ctrl_cmd(conn->engine, "LOAD_CERT_CTRL",
      |         ^~
In file included from ../src/crypto/tls_openssl.c:25:
/usr/include/openssl/engine.h:450:27: note: declared here
  450 | OSSL_DEPRECATEDIN_3_0 int ENGINE_ctrl_cmd(ENGINE *e, const char *cmd_name,
      |                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../src/crypto/tls_openssl.c: In function ‘tls_connection_private_key’:
../src/crypto/tls_openssl.c:3827:17: error: ‘SSL_use_RSAPrivateKey_ASN1’ is deprecated: Since OpenSSL 3.0 [-Werror=deprecated-declarations]
 3827 |                 if (SSL_use_RSAPrivateKey_ASN1(conn->ssl,
      |                 ^~
In file included from ../src/crypto/tls_openssl.c:19:
/usr/include/openssl/ssl.h:1652:12: note: declared here
 1652 | __owur int SSL_use_RSAPrivateKey_ASN1(SSL *ssl,
      |            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../src/crypto/tls_openssl.c: In function ‘tls_connection_dh’:
../src/crypto/tls_openssl.c:3966:9: error: ‘PEM_read_bio_DHparams’ is deprecated: Since OpenSSL 3.0 [-Werror=deprecated-declarations]
 3966 |         dh = PEM_read_bio_DHparams(bio, NULL, NULL, NULL);
      |         ^~
In file included from /usr/include/openssl/ssl.h:36,
                 from ../src/crypto/tls_openssl.c:19:
/usr/include/openssl/pem.h:469:1: note: declared here
  469 | DECLARE_PEM_rw_attr(OSSL_DEPRECATEDIN_3_0, DHparams, DH)
      | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../src/crypto/tls_openssl.c:3977:17: error: ‘PEM_read_bio_DSAparams’ is deprecated: Since OpenSSL 3.0 [-Werror=deprecated-declarations]
 3977 |                 dsa = PEM_read_bio_DSAparams(bio, NULL, NULL, NULL);
      |                 ^~~
In file included from /usr/include/openssl/ssl.h:36,
                 from ../src/crypto/tls_openssl.c:19:
/usr/include/openssl/pem.h:455:1: note: declared here
  455 | DECLARE_PEM_rw_attr(OSSL_DEPRECATEDIN_3_0, DSAparams, DSA)
      | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../src/crypto/tls_openssl.c:3987:17: error: ‘DSA_dup_DH’ is deprecated: Since OpenSSL 3.0 [-Werror=deprecated-declarations]
 3987 |                 dh = DSA_dup_DH(dsa);
      |                 ^~
In file included from /usr/include/openssl/x509.h:37,
                 from /usr/include/openssl/ssl.h:31,
                 from ../src/crypto/tls_openssl.c:19:
/usr/include/openssl/dsa.h:198:27: note: declared here
  198 | OSSL_DEPRECATEDIN_3_0 DH *DSA_dup_DH(const DSA *r);
      |                           ^~~~~~~~~~
../src/crypto/tls_openssl.c:3988:17: error: ‘DSA_free’ is deprecated: Since OpenSSL 3.0 [-Werror=deprecated-declarations]
 3988 |                 DSA_free(dsa);
      |                 ^~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/openssl/x509.h:37,
                 from /usr/include/openssl/ssl.h:31,
                 from ../src/crypto/tls_openssl.c:19:
/usr/include/openssl/dsa.h:127:28: note: declared here
  127 | OSSL_DEPRECATEDIN_3_0 void DSA_free(DSA *r);
      |                            ^~~~~~~~
../src/crypto/tls_openssl.c:4007:17: error: ‘DH_free’ is deprecated: Since OpenSSL 3.0 [-Werror=deprecated-declarations]
 4007 |                 DH_free(dh);
      |                 ^~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/openssl/dsa.h:51,
                 from /usr/include/openssl/x509.h:37,
                 from /usr/include/openssl/ssl.h:31,
                 from ../src/crypto/tls_openssl.c:19:
/usr/include/openssl/dh.h:200:28: note: declared here
  200 | OSSL_DEPRECATEDIN_3_0 void DH_free(DH *dh);
      |                            ^~~~~~~
../src/crypto/tls_openssl.c:4010:9: error: ‘DH_free’ is deprecated: Since OpenSSL 3.0 [-Werror=deprecated-declarations]
 4010 |         DH_free(dh);
      |         ^~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/openssl/dsa.h:51,
                 from /usr/include/openssl/x509.h:37,
                 from /usr/include/openssl/ssl.h:31,
                 from ../src/crypto/tls_openssl.c:19:
/usr/include/openssl/dh.h:200:28: note: declared here
  200 | OSSL_DEPRECATEDIN_3_0 void DH_free(DH *dh);
      |                            ^~~~~~~
../src/crypto/tls_openssl.c: In function ‘tls_global_dh’:
../src/crypto/tls_openssl.c:4041:9: error: ‘PEM_read_bio_DHparams’ is deprecated: Since OpenSSL 3.0 [-Werror=deprecated-declarations]
 4041 |         dh = PEM_read_bio_DHparams(bio, NULL, NULL, NULL);
      |         ^~
In file included from /usr/include/openssl/ssl.h:36,
                 from ../src/crypto/tls_openssl.c:19:
/usr/include/openssl/pem.h:469:1: note: declared here
  469 | DECLARE_PEM_rw_attr(OSSL_DEPRECATEDIN_3_0, DHparams, DH)
      | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../src/crypto/tls_openssl.c:4052:17: error: ‘PEM_read_bio_DSAparams’ is deprecated: Since OpenSSL 3.0 [-Werror=deprecated-declarations]
 4052 |                 dsa = PEM_read_bio_DSAparams(bio, NULL, NULL, NULL);
      |                 ^~~
In file included from /usr/include/openssl/ssl.h:36,
                 from ../src/crypto/tls_openssl.c:19:
/usr/include/openssl/pem.h:455:1: note: declared here
  455 | DECLARE_PEM_rw_attr(OSSL_DEPRECATEDIN_3_0, DSAparams, DSA)
      | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../src/crypto/tls_openssl.c:4062:17: error: ‘DSA_dup_DH’ is deprecated: Since OpenSSL 3.0 [-Werror=deprecated-declarations]
 4062 |                 dh = DSA_dup_DH(dsa);
      |                 ^~
In file included from /usr/include/openssl/x509.h:37,
                 from /usr/include/openssl/ssl.h:31,
                 from ../src/crypto/tls_openssl.c:19:
/usr/include/openssl/dsa.h:198:27: note: declared here
  198 | OSSL_DEPRECATEDIN_3_0 DH *DSA_dup_DH(const DSA *r);
      |                           ^~~~~~~~~~
../src/crypto/tls_openssl.c:4063:17: error: ‘DSA_free’ is deprecated: Since OpenSSL 3.0 [-Werror=deprecated-declarations]
 4063 |                 DSA_free(dsa);
      |                 ^~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/openssl/x509.h:37,
                 from /usr/include/openssl/ssl.h:31,
                 from ../src/crypto/tls_openssl.c:19:
/usr/include/openssl/dsa.h:127:28: note: declared here
  127 | OSSL_DEPRECATEDIN_3_0 void DSA_free(DSA *r);
      |                            ^~~~~~~~
../src/crypto/tls_openssl.c:4082:17: error: ‘DH_free’ is deprecated: Since OpenSSL 3.0 [-Werror=deprecated-declarations]
 4082 |                 DH_free(dh);
      |                 ^~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/openssl/dsa.h:51,
                 from /usr/include/openssl/x509.h:37,
                 from /usr/include/openssl/ssl.h:31,
                 from ../src/crypto/tls_openssl.c:19:
/usr/include/openssl/dh.h:200:28: note: declared here
  200 | OSSL_DEPRECATEDIN_3_0 void DH_free(DH *dh);
      |                            ^~~~~~~
../src/crypto/tls_openssl.c:4085:9: error: ‘DH_free’ is deprecated: Since OpenSSL 3.0 [-Werror=deprecated-declarations]
 4085 |         DH_free(dh);
      |         ^~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/openssl/dsa.h:51,
                 from /usr/include/openssl/x509.h:37,
                 from /usr/include/openssl/ssl.h:31,
                 from ../src/crypto/tls_openssl.c:19:
/usr/include/openssl/dh.h:200:28: note: declared here
  200 | OSSL_DEPRECATEDIN_3_0 void DH_free(DH *dh);
      |                            ^~~~~~~
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
make: *** [../src/build.rules:86: /root/radiusconfig/wpa_supplicant-2.10/build/wpa_supplicant/src/crypto/tls_openssl.o] Error 1
```

originally posted on

```
"freeradius-users" <freeradius-users@lists.freeradius.org> and
"hostap" <hostap@lists.infradead.org>
```

Comment: Meanwhile I found there is an eapoltest ubuntu deb package that apears to work

Comment: Short of re-writing the code, to build it against OpenSSL 3.0 you'd need to suppress the warnings ex. `CFLAGS=-Wno-deprecated-declarations make eapol_test` - see [Upgrading to OpenSSL 3.0 from OpenSSL 1.1.1](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/OpenSSL_3.0#Upgrading_to_OpenSSL_3.0_from_OpenSSL_1.1.1)